# Writing sequences using $\sum$ and $\prod$ symbols

Tags: sequences-and-series

Rewrite the following expressions using $\sum$ or $\prod$

**a)** $(x-1)(x-4)(x-9)(x-16)....(x-900)$

**b)** $1/(6^3) + 1/(9^4) + 1/(12^5) + 1/(15^6) +......+ 1/(33^{12})$

For part a) I noticed that difference between two side by side values increases by $2$ every step. That is all I noticed I can't seem to find an equation for either of the a) and b) sequences. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you find a pattern in the individual terms: $(x-1)$, then $(x-4)$, then $(x-9)$.  Each term is $(x-\text{*something*})$.  Can you see a pattern in the "somethings"?

Comment: Yes I saw a pattern of 3,4,7,9.... It is increasing by 2

Comment: Perhaps your $4$ should be a $5$?

Comment: Yes it should be. It was a typo

Comment: An extremely useful resource for finding patterns is the [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try to find the pattern:

- For the first sequence: $$1=1^2\\ 4=2^2\\ 9=3^2\\ 16=4^2\\\vdots$$
- For the second sequence: $$6^3 = ((1+1)\cdot 3)^{2+1}\\9^4=((1+2)\cdot 3)^{2+2}\\ 12^5=((1+3)\cdot 3)^{2+3}\\ 15^6=((1+4)\cdot 3)^{2+4}\\\vdots$$

Answer (score 1):

a) $$\prod_{i=1}^{30}(x-i^2)$$

b) $$\sum_{k=2}^{11}\left(\frac{1}{3k}\right)^{k+1}$$

Comment: This answer is correct. But how did you guess it?

Comment: see answer @5xum